index js error when I'm trying to call out a task
I created a yml task on a azure devops pipeline that will send an email once the build is successful but I am getting an error of
##[error]File not found: '/home/vsts/work/_tasks/EmailReportV2_36fd41b1-8024-4ce9-a5a0-53c3e54ed105/2.0.10/Index.js'

I have also tried some alternatives but it couldn't work because of the limitations on the application that we can install on the marketplace
Here's the task code that was provided by the azure devops pipeline
  - task: EmailReportV2@2
    displayName: 'Send Email Report'
    inputs:
      sendMailConditionConfig: 'On Success'
      subject: 'Job Details'
      toAddress: 'myemail@work.com'
      ccAddress: 'myco-workersemail@work.com'
      defaultDomain: 'work.com'
      groupTestResultsBy: 'run'
      includeCommits: true
      maxTestFailuresToShow: '15'
      includeOthersInTotal: false
      usePreviousEnvironment: false
      smtpConnectionEndpoint: 'SMTP Server that we use'


Have you tried to use this task on an windows MS-hosted agent?

we cannot as we are using lunix / ubuntu agent

Hi @JianRuizMangampo, I  tested to use another extension that got modified based on that published by MS DevTestLab. The pipeline worked as well on ubuntu agent with CalromEmailReport@1 task. Please evaluate if you would consider using this one instead.

Update
The same issue was also reported here; if possible, you may consider the workaround to use the 3rd-party extension where the publisher mentioned the issue was fixed.

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: CalromEmailReport@1 # https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=calrom-jtejero.CalromEmailReportExtension
  inputs:
    sendMailConditionConfig: 'Always'
    subject: 'Job details for pipeline build - $(Build.BuildId)'
    toAddress: 'azxxx@xxx.com'
    ccAddress: 'azxxx@xxx.com'
    defaultDomain: 'xxx.com'
    groupTestResultsBy: 'run'
    includeCommits: true
    maxTestFailuresToShow: '15'
    includeOthersInTotal: false
    usePreviousEnvironment: false
    smtpConnectionEndpoint: 'xxxSMTPServer'


I could reproduce the issue when running the marketplace extension task EmailReportV2@2 on the Microsoft-hosted agents of both ubuntu-latest and ubuntu-22.04.

While the same pipeline running on windows-latest agent was working.  If possible, you may opt to use this VM image as of now.

It is also suggested visiting the extension publisher's GitHub repo and reporting a new issue.
